# Error: window.sinon is undefined

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, sinon, slimerjs

I am using casperjs which in turn runs on slimerjs along with phantomxhr. I am not sure of the support of phantomxhr with slimerjs+capserjs but I am getting 'window.sinon is undefined' error while running the code (Error at Phantomxhr.js line 124). Everything is working fine when running casperjs with phantomjs.

Looks like there is an problem while injecting the sinon js script as given phantomxhr (line 24). So what I did is, add a line in the test file `'phantom.injectJs('Absolute path to sinon.js file').` This doesn't even open the browser. what I am doing wrong. Any pointer would help.